# Switching line properties while using NSBezierPath

Tags: cocoa, graphics

I'm having some very basic problems changing line color/width when drawing different lines (intended for a chart) with NSBezierPath. The following code should make it clear what I'm trying to do:

```
#import "DrawTest.h"

@implementation DrawTest

- (id)initWithFrame:(NSRect)frameRect
{
NSLog(@"in 'initWithFrame'...");
    if ((self = [super initWithFrame:frameRect]) != nil)
        {
    [self drawBaseline];
    [self display]; // ...NO!
    [self drawPlotline];
    }
return self;
}

- (void)drawBaseline
{
    NSRect windowRect;
    int width, height;

    windowRect = [self bounds];
    width = round(windowRect.size.width);
    height = round(windowRect.size.height);

    theLineWidth=1.0;
    [[NSColor grayColor] set];
    // allocate an instance of 'NSBezierPath'...
    path = [[NSBezierPath alloc]init];
    // draw a HORIZONTAL line...
    [path moveToPoint:NSMakePoint(0,height/2)];
    [path lineToPoint:NSMakePoint(width,height/2)];
}

- (void)drawPlotline
{
    theLineWidth=10.0;
    [[NSColor redColor] set];
    // draw a VERTICAL line...
    [path moveToPoint:NSMakePoint(100,125)]; // x,y
    [path lineToPoint:NSMakePoint(100,500)];
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect
{
NSLog(@"in 'drawRect'...");
    // draw the path line(s)
    //  [[NSColor redColor] set];
    [path setLineWidth:theLineWidth];
    [path stroke];
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [path release];
    [super dealloc];
}

@end
```

The problem obviously lies in the fact that 'drawRect' only gets called ONCE (after both methods have run), with the result that all lines appear in the last color and line width set. I've tried calling [self display] etc. in the hope of forcing 'drawRect' to redraw the NSView contents between the two method calls, but to no avail.

Can anyone suggest a basic strategy to achieve what I'm trying to do here, please? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You definitely need to read and re-read the Cocoa Drawing Guide as you're fundamentally misunderstanding how Cocoa drawing works. As Yuji points out, your view draws only when it's told to by Cocoa. http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaDrawingGuide/

Comment: Your drawing code in `initWithFrame:` isn't doing anything, because your view isn't in a window yet, because *it hasn't even finished initializing yet*. You need to read the View Programming Guide for Cocoa, in addition to the Cocoa Drawing Guide that Rob Keniger already mentioned. http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/

Comment: Thanks Rob and Peter. Yes, I'll read the documentation. Unfortunately, many of my problems stem from the fact that (1) I'm still struggling to free myself from my old 'proc-C' habits and (2) at age 65, my brain isn't co-operating with me like it used to :-(  Appreciate both of your useful inputs.

Comment: You're twice my age! Keep the good work!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick answer is: move `[self drawBaseline]` and `[self drawPlotline]` inside `drawRect`.
Also, you need to call `[path stroke]` once per color, before changing the color.  So, the pseudo-code is something like

```
-(void)drawRect:(NSRect)rect
{
      NSBezierPath*path1=...
      construct the path for color red...
      [[NSColor redColor] set];
      [path1 stroke]; 

      NSBezierPath*path2=...
      construct the path for color blue...
      [[NSColor blueColor] set];
      [path2 stroke]; 

}
```

Remember:

- `[path moveToPoint:]` etc. does not *draw* the path. It just *constructs* the path inside the object. Once it's constructed, you *stroke* the path using `[path stroke]`.
- Also, the color is not the property of the path constructed inside the `NSBezierPath` instance. So, `[color set]` is not recorded inside your `NSBezierPath` instance! It's the property of the graphic context. Conceptually, 1. you construct the path. 2. you set the color to the context. 3. you stroke the path.
- In Cocoa, it's not that you tell the system when to draw, when to refresh, etc. *Cocoa tells you* when to draw, by calling your `drawRect:`. The graphic context on which you draw is not available outside of `drawRect:`, unless you create off-screen context yourself. So, don't bother drawing beforehand. Just draw everything inside `drawRect` .

Comment: Thanks Yuji, I appreciate your help. It's working great now :-)